# Griddle empty table when objects in fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, griddle

I'm trying [Griddle](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/) grid component for React. When I pass an array of objects with primitive fields everything works fine

```
<Griddle results={[{id: 42}]}/> // works
```

but when there are objects in fields, it shows an empty table

```
<Griddle results={[{id: {value: 42}}]}/> // doesn't work
```

I have complex objects in fields and custom components to display them but the table is just empty. How do I make it work?

Comment: I am having a similar problem too.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around this limitation of Griddle with [customComponent](http://griddlegriddle.github.io/Griddle/customization.html#customColumns).  In your case the code would look the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import Griddle from 'griddle-react';

const GriddleValueComponent = props => (<div>{props.data.value}</div>);

var MyComponent = (props) => {

    const columnMetadata = [
        {
            "columnName": "id",
            "order": 1,
            "displayName": "The Value",
            "customComponent": GriddleValueComponent
        }
    ];

    return (
        <div className="cssmFsaDataList">
            <Griddle results={[{id: {value: 42}}]} columnMetadata={columnMetadata} columns={["id"]} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Which renders as this:

[image]